# Stop jQuery.typewriter plugin being executed when input is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a typewriter plugin, which should animate the placeholder of an input when this form is visible. This works. However, I'd like to stop this animation, when the searchbar is not visible anymore (eg. on esc event).

```
    tg_search = function() {
        var search_icon = $('.tg-search'),
            header = $('.fusion-header'),
            writing = false;
        var search_tl = new TimelineMax({
            reversed: true,
            paused: true,
        })
        search_tl
            .to('.tgicon-search.-open', 0.2, {autoAlpha: 0, display: 'none'})
            .to('.tgicon-search.-close', 0.2, {autoAlpha: 1, display: 'inline'})
            .to('.tg-search__wrapper', 0.5, {y: 0, autoAlpha: 1});

        search_icon.click(function (e) {
            /*event.preventDefault();*/
            writing = true;
            search_tl.reversed() ? search_tl.play() : search_tl.reverse();
        });

        // ESC Event
        $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                !search_tl.reversed() && search_tl.reverse();
                 writing = false;
            }
        });

        function typewriter() {
            if (!writing) {
                return;
            } else {
                $('#type-search').placeholderTypewriter({text: ["What are you looking for?"]});
            }
        };
    };
```

I tried it with a boolean, and ended up with failure. I also tried to replace the input form without placeholder within the esc event, but the plugin keeps adding the palceholder correspondending to the id of the element. If you click the search icon again, the function is even executed twice, so the placeholder text is nonsense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [Visible Selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout.
>
> Elements that are not in a document are considered hidden; jQuery does not have a way to know if they will be visible when appended to a document since it depends on the applicable styles.
>
> This selector is the opposite of the :hidden selector. So, every element selected by :visible isn't selected by :hidden and vice versa.

```
    function typewriter() {
        if (!writing) {
            return;
        } else {
            $('#type-search:visible').placeholderTypewriter({text: ["What are you looking for?"]});
        }
    };
```